# Why is Passport JS local strategy not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate user using passportjs local strategy. It works on Postman but not when I connect to React frontend.

server:

index.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import passport from "passport";
import session from "express-session";
import feedRoute from './routes/feed.routes.js';
import userRoute from './routes/users.routes.js';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

dotenv.config();
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
}));
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.send("John Doe")})

app.use('/feed', feedRoute);
app.use('/user', userRoute);

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL,{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(()=>app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server running on Port : ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error)=>console.log(error.message));
```

user.routes.js:

```
import express from "express";
import User from "../models/user.js";
import passport from "passport";
import initializingPassport from "../passportConfig.js";

initializingPassport(passport);

const router = express.Router();

// register api here that works

router.route('/login').post(passport.authenticate("local", { failureFlash: true }), (req, res)=> {
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({message:"Logged in"}));
})

export default router;
```

feed.routes.js:

```
import express from 'express';

import passport from "passport";
import initializingPassport, {isAuthenticated} from "../passportConfig.js";

const router = express.Router();
initializingPassport(passport)

router.route('/').get(isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    res.json({ message: 'Authenticated' });
});

export default router;
```

passportConfig.js:

```
import {Strategy as LocalStrategy} from "passport-local";
import User from "./models/user.js";

export default function initializePassport(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, async function (email, password, done) {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
        }
        if (!(await user.comparePassword(password))) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try{
      const user = await User.findById(id)
      done(null, user);

    } catch(error) {
      done(error, false);
    }
  })
}

export function isAuthenticated(req, res, done) {
  if(req.user) return done();

  res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({'message': "Not Authenticated"}))
}
```

After /login is called, /feed is called but that doesn't seem to be working. It keeps saying `Not Authenticated` even though the session is stored in MongoDB and I can see it.

Can someone help?

Calling /user/login :

```
const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const response=await fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/login',{
      method:'POST',
      body:JSON.stringify(details),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      
    })
    const res= await response.json()
    console.log(res)
    if(res.message==='400'){
      seterr('Login failed')
      console.log(err)}
    else{
      seterr('')
      nav('/feed')
    }
  }
```

Sending GET request from Feed:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Feed = () => {
  const nav = new useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
      const ftechData = async() => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/feed', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
  
        const data = await res.json();
  
        if(data.message!='Authenticated'){
          console.log(data.message)
          nav('/login')
        } 
      }
      ftechData()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='header-text'>Feed</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please show how do you call the endpoint in react

Comment: I have edited it in at the bottom. Please take a look!